# Rename tag [coup-the-resistance] to [coup]

Tags: discussion

Currently we have [coup-the-resistance](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/coup-the-resistance). This reflects the working title of the game during [its Kickstarter drive](https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/2012515236/coup-bluff-and-deception-in-the-world-of-the-resis). However, the final title of the game when it was shipped was simply "Coup", as the [listing on Board Game Geek](https://www.boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/131357/coup) shows (it doesn't even list the working title as one of its alternate titles).

Could we please rename the tag from [coup-the-resistance](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/coup-the-resistance) to [coup](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/coup)? I'm not sure that a tag synonym is necessary, but would not be opposed to having it if others feel it should be there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Done.

Hmmm, need to fill the space so I'll just note that for six questions to be retagged, I'm not sure a moderator was needed. :)

Comment: I thought that only moderators could rename tags, so I'm a bit confused about why they would not be needed.

Comment: I don't think anyone can "rename tags" - at least I don't think I can on the site I moderate... maybe I can and just don't know? I bet all he did was remove the [tag:coup-the-resistance] and add [tag:coup].

Comment: Moderators have a tool called "merge tags" which removes the old tag and adds the new one.  My point was that for six posts, it isn't overly necessary to go that route. :)

Comment: Well, the other reason for the post was to gather community opinion, which I think is a good idea before renaming an entire tag.